# Pointer operand required when merging pointer strings

Tags: c

I am attempting to concatenate string 2 behind string 1, and then assign this string into a final string. All of these strings are passed into the function as pointers. I am getting an error when I am setting my final string pointer to the two strings.

My expected input/output:

```
concat("string", 10, "hello", "world");
--> char *final should be: helloworld
```

My concat function:

```
void concat(char *final, size_t max, const char *first, const char *second)
{
    //final holds first+second
    //max is the size of first and second strings combined
    //first and second are strings

    while (*first != '\0') {
        first++;
    }
    while (*second != '\0') {
        *first = *second;
        first++;
        second++;
    }
    *first = '\0';
    *final[max] = *first;    // Error on this line
}
```

My error (line 15):

```
Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
```

edit:
`const` may be removed to avoid read-only variable assignment error.

Comment: is that really the full error?  it doesn't have a line number?

Comment: You should also have error messages on both assignments to `*first`.

Comment: @KeithThompson how does my edit look?

Comment: You can't use `"string"` as the first argument; it's a string literal and attempts to modify a string literal lead to undefined behaviour — usually a crash.  You need to provide an actual array of characters that is big enough for the two source strings.  And it isn't really clear what `max` is meant to represent.  You have 10 characters plus a null byte in your desired result string — this bears no resemblance to the space available in `"string"`.

Comment: Does your actual code include the `const` keywords on the parameter declarations? With the code in the question you should have gotten multiple compile-time errors, but you only asked about one of them. Either include all the error messages in your question, or show us code that exhibits just the problem that you're asking about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did not consider the null byte, so "max" is the length of the strings plus the null byte. Thanks for pointing out that "final" should be an array of characters. The capacity of "final" should be "max" to hold "first" and "second" string together. I was not sure how to concatenate those two strings into the "final" array.

Comment: @KeithThompson My apologies, I will consider listing all of my error messages next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`final` is a pointer to `char`. `final[max]` is the character at the position `max` relative to `final`. It effectively includes an `*` operation, so you do not need one. In `*final[max] = *first;`, the first `*` is not needed.

In fact, `final[max]` is defined to be `*(final + max)`, meaning to take the pointer `final`, adjust it by `max` elements, and then refer to the `char` that is at that location. `*final[max]` would be `**(final + max)`, which is not what you want.

It is not clear what you intend to accomplish with `final[max] = *first;`. At this point, `first` is pointing to the `'\0'` that you just wrote to it, so `final[max] = *first;` will set `final[max]` to `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I intended to point final to *first+*second to form helloworld as those are the values for first and second. I was not entirely sure the order to set the array to *first+*second.